# Blow up of the sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology

I am trying to show that if we blow up the sphere twice ($S^2$) we basically get the Klein bottle. I understand that blowing up is basically attaching a copy of $RP^2$ but not sure where to go from there. Any help/hint?

Comment: You’re doing real blow-up, so the algebraic geometry tag is likely confusing.

Comment: One usual argument runs: 1. (As indicated in the question,) real blowing-up a point amounts to connect summing with a projective plane, i.e., 2. with a Moebius strip. 3. A Klein bottle amounts to a connected sum of two Moebius strips.

Comment: @Mariano, I certainly know that. But this is a basic topology question. :) And, no, it’s connect sum with $\Bbb RP^2$, as OP said. You replace the point with an $\Bbb RP^1$.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question, but I think going about it by using the fact that $\mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2 \cong K$ is not very enlightening. Instead try to use the fact that $K$ is uniquely identified as the nontrivial $S^1$ bundle over $S^1$, and try to show that blowing up $S^2$ at each pole gives the total space of such a bundle. The bundle is very pretty!