# Real blow up of a surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, blowup

I was self studying blow up in algebraic geometry. My question is what is the blow up of compact surfaces? Does there exists any relation of Euler characteristics of base space and the blown up space? Can we get any compact surface by blowing up a suitable sub space of sphere? In particular
Can we obtain torus as a blow up of sphere over some discrete set? A related question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4558625/blow-up-of-the-sphere) but I do not understand it precisely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that by a "surface" you mean a manifold of real dimension 2, the blow-up amounts to the connected sum with the real projective plane. Now, you should be able to answer your own question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan does he centre of the blow up is not needed.

Comment: I have no idea what your question means.

Comment: I am asking that instead of discrete set of we blow up a surface over a curve then what will be the situation?

Comment: Nothing will happen, assuming that the curve is smooth. Otherwise, I do not know.